# Take a specific date interval by python

Tags: python

assume I have two dates, 2010-01-01 and 2018-12-30, I want to take the first day of every month like 2010-01-01, 2010-02-01,2010-03-01......2018-12-01.Or take a date by a specific interval like take one day every 100 days. How can I achieve this function by python? Is there a library can use? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pendulum:

> https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/

It is very handy to handle dates.

You can do the following to get dates by interval.

```
import pendulum

start = pendulum.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = pendulum.datetime(2019, 12, 31)

period = pendulum.period(start, end)

for date in period.range('days', 100):
    print(date)
```

You can see more about range here:

> https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#range

Answer (score 1):

In addition, I would like to offer a script for scheduling jobs, I use the '**schedule**' module.

please visit the website for installation and more details: 
https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

It **answers the original question** and allows for multiple jobs to be scheduled and even the same job scheduled at different intervals, I added some sample tasks to illustrate the functionality

- In this cased I used the `datetime` module to format the dates
- Then I list the functions I would like to execute:

  - Notice `job()` holds the date conditions, if they are not met then it will `pass`
- Then we schedule the jobs by calling the `schedule` module, you can list as many jobs as you need to execute and the `schedule` module offers a lot of flexibility.
- In order to continuously check for pending jobs we run a `while True:` loop and checking the `schedule.run_pending()` method at a set interval by using the `time.sleep()` function

---

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import schedule

# ----------------------------- date format -------------- #
now = datetime.now()
todays_year = now.strftime("%Y")
todays_month = now.strftime("%m")
todays_day = now.strftime("%d")

start_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
start_date_y = start_date.strftime("%Y")
start_dat_m = start_date.strftime("%m")

end_date = datetime(2019, 12, 31)
end_date_y = end_date.strftime("%Y")
end_date_m = end_date.strftime("%m")

# ----------------------------- pending functions ------- #


def job():
    """
    This function will print today's date, if date conditions are met,
    it could also perform other tasks, like write to a file or DB.
    """
    if int(start_dat_m) < int(todays_month) < int(end_date_m) and int(todays_year) == int(start_date_y):
        print(now.strftime("%Y, %m, %d"))
    else:
        pass


def another_job():
    print('another job')


def yet_another_job():
    print('yet another job')


# ----------------------------- job scheduler --------- #

# Answers question
schedule.every(100).days.do(job)

# Sample jobs
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job)
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(another_job)
schedule.every(1).minute.do(yet_another_job)


# ----------------------------- run pending method - #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: oh, thanks. It’s really powerful. I need some time to learn it